# node-elastic full document update

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

In my nodejs elastic writer I want to replace one document with another. 
Currently, I run-

```
            var data = { doc: doc, "doc_as_upsert": true };            
            var metadata = 
            { update: { _id: idToUpdate, _index:indexName,_type: INDEX_TYPE_PREFIX } };
            body.push(metadata);
            body.push(payment);    
        } 
        elasticsearchClient.bulk({
            body: body,
        }, function (err, resp) {
```

But in case the document in elastic contained field X and the updated document didn't, field X stays in elastic- I want it to be removed. 
According to 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html
using "doc:" is for partial update, so what's the alternative for full update?

Comment: Just delete and index again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the update api, use the index api instead.